# read JSON to PHP from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have an API that is available only in javascript (no PHP). It fetches some data of which I made a JSON string. What I need to know is how do I read this string in other page?

I tried using following :

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
```

but of course the string I get is not JSON but is actually the javascript code that will generate json in original page. Any suggestions ?
Thank you.

P.S. I also tried set cookie + redirect. Though that worked, I'd like to know a better solution.

Here is the javascript code

```
            function searchComplete() {

                 if (imageSearch.results && imageSearch.results.length > 0)
                 {
                    var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
                    contentDiv.innerHTML = '';
                    var results = imageSearch.results;

                    var data = "{['data' : [\n";

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                        //var result = results[i];
                        var result = results[i];

                        data += "{\n";
                        data += "'url' : '"+result.url+"'";
                        data += "\n},\n";

                   }
                   data += "]]}";
                   setCookie("datajson", data, 1); // This is how i set the cookie and redirected
                   window.location = "JSPHP.php?data="+data;

                document.getElementById('body').innerHTML = data;
                  }
            }
```

Comment: Can you show what the Javascript looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you said it is not JSON. Thus [json_decode()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function is useless here without additional things. If this happens on browser side, you should probably pass the data to the server using AJAX.

Alternatively you can take a look how this API works (maybe it connects with some server using JSONs to exchange data?) and do the same in PHP.

**EDIT:**

You do not need to create a string of JSON on JavaScript side. JSON is itself object notation in JavaScript.

If you need to pass the data, just do something similar to this:

```
var data = [];
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    data[] = {
        'url': result.url
    };
}
```

Then you only need to pass this data to the server. You can use [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function (if you need to pass it using GET) from jQuery like that:

```
jQuery.get('http://example.com/', data, function(){
    // something to do when successful
});
```

It is pretty simple and the basic is: create data correctly and pass it to the server using AJAX call.

Answer (score 2):

PHP have great module for it:

```
json_encode
json_decode
```

Comment: mihsathe said: `the string I get is not JSON but is actually the javascript code that will generate json in original page`. How do you want to use json_decode() for parsing JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself a web page that executes the javascript and saves the JSON result. Then post the JSON data to a PHP script (via XmlHttpRequest or regular form POST). Now your PHP code has access to the JSON data, and you can use `json_decode` to access it.

Comment: I tried same using a cookie (code added). Problem is when I want to access my json from other (third) page from maybe other web site. The problem is which page do I call. If I call the first, its useless. But if I call second, there's no cookie with it.

Comment: Though using database is an option, that will be a shame .. lol